# Java - Getting rid of NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Think about two cases case1 and case2 plus two methods method1 and method2. Say method1 solves case1 and method2 solves case2. Now, I have a program that might end up with case1 or case2. In my codes, I call method1 no matter what case happens. But, if case2 occurs, method1 gives a nullpointerexception.

What I want is the following: my codes should call method1 first, if an exception occurs, then method2 is called. How am I gonna do that? Since I have no info about try and catch, I really need some help!

Comment: I think some code is better than any explanations.

Comment: I guess you are right. Say I have TreeNode<City> parentNode which will be the left hand of an equality and the right hand will be search(parent,this) or search2(parent,this). Yet, search and search2 might return null, which I do not want. Now, how should I implement?

Comment: please edit your question and post some code sample, not just variable names and method signatures.

Comment: You could call search1(), then check whether the result is null, and if so, then call search2. If search2 is also null, the equality test should fail.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
    try {
        method1();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        method2();
    }
```

That said, it's typically better to rely on exceptions only for exceptional conditions. For normal flow of control, you can use an if:

```
    if ( isCase2() ) {
        method2();
    }
    else {
        method1();
    }
```

Comment: As @Vladimir posted, if you're going to go with try/catch, it's better to throw your own exception object from method1 than to rely on a NPE (which might arise even in case 1 due to other problems).

Comment: Agreed. The first example above is intended to satisfy the OP literally: "my codes should call method1 first, if an exception occurs, then method2 is called." If you can distinguish between case1 and case2 a priori, then that's preferable to using any exception.

Comment: Absolutely. Use exceptions for exceptional situations. This sounds like having one case versus another is not exceptional at all.

Answer (score 2):

Catching `NullPointerException` is a bad pratice - you may catch not the particular exception you want to catch. You have two options:

1) Throw your own exception and catch it later:

```
  public void method1(Case caze) throws MyException {
    if (case.getType() == CaseType.CaseOne) {
       // processing
    } else {
       throw new MyException("Wrong case type");
    }
  }
```

And the client code:

```
try {
   method1(caze);
} catch (MyException e) {
   // log the excpetion
   method2(caze);
}
```

2) Return a boolean flag, indicating that the processing has been succesfully finished.

Remember, that it is alway better to analyze the values than use try-catch mechanism in your situations. I would suggest variant #2 for you.